# Change path.expand location (Win 7)

Tags: r

Currently:

```
path.expand("~")
```

Gives:

```
"C:\\Users\\trinker\\Documents"
```

I want it to yield:

```
"C:\\Users\\trinker"
```

The directory for the windows command prompt is `C:\Users\trinker`.  This indicates that this is my windows home directory.

`?path.expand` tells me to look at the rw-FAQ [(LINK)](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f).  This gives information above my cognitive ability.  I decided to try to experiment as below:

```
> Sys.getenv("R_USER")
[1] "C:\\Users\\trinker\\Documents"
> normalizePath("~")
[1] "C:\\Users\\trinker\\Documents"

> Sys.getenv("R_USER") <- "C:\\Users\\trinker"
Error in Sys.getenv("R_USER") <- "C:\\Users\\trinker" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
> normalizePath("~") <- "C:\\Users\\trinker"
Error in normalizePath("~") <- "C:\\Users\\trinker" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I saw:

```
Sys.setenv(...)
Sys.unsetenv(x)
```

But got scared I was messing with things I ought not be blindly messing with and decided to ask for guidance.

So again I would like to have `~` mean `C:\\Users\\trinker\\` again (this was the default for my last PC) not the `C:\\Users\\trinker\\Documents` it is now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To persistently reset the directory that `"~"` resolves to for all users, put the following in the file `Renviron.site`, located in `$RHOME/etc/Renviron.site`:

```
R_USER="C:/Users/trinker"
```

(If the file is not already there, you can just create it yourself.)

---

If a computer supports multiple R users, and each wants to set their own `R_USER` location, each can put the following in their own `".Rprofile"` file:

```
Sys.setenv(R_USER = "C:/Users/trinker")
```

`".Rprofile"` is looked for in the user's home directory, which is returned by typing `Sys.getenv("HOME")`. See `?Startup` and [the R for Windows FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f) for more details.

(Thanks to @Dason for pointing out the `.Rprofile` option.)

Comment: @GSee -- Thanks. I'd simply mis-typed, and you caught it just as I did.

Comment: Putting it in Renviron.site would affect all users on the computer right?  Although I'm fairly sure Tyler is the only one using R on his computer this still seems less than adequate.  Would adding a Sys.setenv call to .Rprofile be better? `Sys.setenv(R_USER = "C:/Users/trinker")` inside of .First should do it.

Comment: @Dason -- Yes, that's the better solution if you've got several R users on a single computer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The first option did not work for me while the .Rprofile did.  I assume this is because I have an .Rprofile I use and R uses this from my wd before searching for Renviron.site. +1 Dasona and Josh.

Comment: @TylerRinker -- Or at least something like that. `?Startup` indicates that `Renviron.site` is read before any `.Rprofile` files (so settings in `.Rprofile` can overwrite settings from `Renviron.site`. In any case, glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to update the 'target' string in the shortcut you use to launch a new R session. To to that, right click the icon, and select "Properties" from the context menu.  Select the "Shortcut" tab of the dialog box, and add one the following name/value pairs to the `target` field.

```
R_USER="c:\my\favorite\folder"
R_USER="%USERPROFILE%"
```

Now `path.expand("~")` will expand to `c:\my\favorite\folder` or to `c:\users\my name\`.

A couple of notes.

- This will also change where R looks for user files such as `.Rprofile`,`Rconsole`, and user package library.
- If you've pinned R to your taskbar, you need to right click the task bar Icon to find the shortcut icon which launches R from the taskbar (pictured below):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Our sysadmin has setup the system in such a way that path.expand("~") or
normalizePath("~") always lead to a mapped drive (\...). Creating a ".Renviron " file within the folder pointed by path.expand("~") with following content solved the problem for me :)

```
R_USER="C:/Users/animeshs"
HOME="C:/Users/animeshs"
```

So now

> path.expand("~")

[1] "C:/Users/animeshs"