# How to reset path.expand on tilde

Tags: r

On Windows, in my RProfile.site, I used to set:

```
Sys.setenv(R_USER="/my/desired/path/to/tilde")
```

However, this does not create the same effect on Ubuntu. Any ideas on how I can achieve the same effect? Such that when I type ~ in a path it expands to R_USER?

Here's an example. On Windows, after setting R_USER, in my scripts I would use the following:

```
read.csv("~/Project")
```

Where "~" expanded to /some/path/to/projects/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004531/change-path-expand-location-win-7

Comment: You have to set the environment variable _before_ you start R

Comment: And `Renviron` / `Renviron.site` are good for that, see `help(Startup)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define HOME="/my/projects/folder", preferably for R only, in .Renviron

Functionality for changing the method of `~` path expansion on windows does not exist in the same fashion as Windows as it does in Ubuntu/Linux*

Comment: I have all my project files in the same directory and I'd like R to start looking there. So when I type ~/ it expands to /my/projects/folder/

Comment: Define HOME="/my/projects/folder", preferably for R only, in `.Renviron`.

Comment: I added this line to /etc/R/Rpofile.site - didn't seem to have any effect. Was it supposed to be defined somewhere else?

Comment: See `help(Startup)` which needs several paragraphs to explain this. I can't beat that in 200 chars...  [ It might be that you cannot override HOME, dunno... ]

Comment: Didn't notice that you specified ".Renviron". Thanks for that.

Comment: That worked for path.expand("~"), but it seems to have changed other things as well (like the path to my packages).

Comment: Of course. $HOME is used for many things. Personally, I would just do `ln -s /my/path/to/projects ~/proj` and from there on refer to `~/proj/...`.  But you asked for an override of `~` (== `$HOME`) and now you got to live with the consequences ;-)

Comment: In Windows, setting R_USER, made the tilde function as a call to path/to/proj/ is this not possible in ubuntu?

Comment: [This says](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f): "If environment variable R_USER is set, its value is used. Otherwise if environment variable HOME is set, its value is used".  However, I find that `$HOME=/home/garrett/tmp R --slave -e 'print(path.expand("~"))'` works, but `$R_USER=/home/garrett/tmp R --slave -e 'print(path.expand("~"))'` does not

Comment: @GSee: But aren't you quoting from the R-on-Windows FAQ trying to infer behaviour on Ubuntu? The two OS and implementations are sometimes different, see the R sources...

Comment: Haha. Oops. Good catch @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: And I surmise this also covers your Q. Just because it works on Windoze...

Comment: Yeah, "Not possible". Sad panda.

Comment: I'm not a programmer. In my eyes, C++ is the enemy. Maybe I can bust out the old "Structured C for Engineering" textbook from first year? HA.