# Where is the location of "~" defined in R?

Tags: r, julia

I am running Windows 10 64bit Pro.

I tried to run

```
path.expand("~")
```

in RStudio and it gave me

```
[1] "C:/Users/my_username/Documents"
```

However I tried to use Julia's RCall.jl

```
using RCall
R"path.expand('~')"
```

but it gave me

```
[1] "C:/Users/my_username/"
```

And they are both use the same R binaries. I wonder how is the folder "~" defined in R under Windows?

Comment: The result in RStudio looks much more suspicious (retry with R terminal session?). Since the same code is being run for both calls, it is strange to get different results.

Comment: i did try. its the same as rstudio.

Comment: And what does Julia's `expanduser("~")` give?

Comment: "RStudio" is just "R". The IDE doesn't usurp that particular function like it does a few others. Is it possible your Windows julia installation picked up a different (and weirdly compiled) R when it precompiled the RCall module? Do you get the same conflicting results after running the path expand call after doing `Base.compilecache("RCall")`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460556/how-to-reset-path-expand-on-tilde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in the environment variable `HOME`:

```
> path.expand("~")
[1] "U:/Data"
> Sys.getenv("HOME")
[1] "U:/Data"
```

Comment: how is HOME defined and why is it different for different programs

Comment: @xiaodai You can change an environment variable for the current session with `Sys.setenv`, and you can change it definitely in the `Renviron` file.

Comment: I actually just solve it by doing .libPath(new_path). It's actually a bug in JuliaI https://github.com/JuliaInterop/RCall.jl/issues/206#issuecomment-338799926