# How to set R environment in /etc/profile?

Tags: r, environment

my os is debian6,there is a libR.pc after i compile to install R

```
root@debian:/home/tiger# cat /home/tiger/R-2.15.1/lib/pkgconfig/libR.pc  
rhome=/home/tiger/R-2.15.1/lib/R  
rlibdir=${rhome}/lib  
rincludedir=/home/tiger/R-2.15.1/lib/R/include  
Name: libR  
Description: R as a library  
Version: 2.15.1  
Libs: -L${rlibdir} -lR  
Cflags: -I${rincludedir} -I${rincludedir}  
Libs.private:
```

when set  R  environment in  /etc/profile:
R_HOME= /home/tiger/R-2.15.1
or
R_HOME= /home/tiger/R-2.15.1/lib/R
which line will i choose to write in  /etc/profile?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004531/change-path-expand-location-win-7

Answer (score 1):

On a Debian (or derivative such as Ubuntu system) you have `/etc/R/` to set variable which R uses:

```
edd@max:~$ ls -l /etc/R/
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  602 Jun 17 20:29 ldpaths
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5461 Jun 17 20:29 Makeconf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1868 Mar 31 13:50 Renviron
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  608 Sep 25  2009 Renviron.site
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1159 Mar 31 08:03 repositories
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  792 Oct 28  2009 Rprofile.site
edd@max:~$
```

and the files in `R_HOME/etc/` should be softlinks --- at least if you use the prebuilt binaries.   If you build you own binaries, it's your problem.

The file you quote is installed as `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libR.pc` on a Debian / Ubuntu system.  Setting `R_HOME` is *not* needed as `R` finds its own values (see @flodel's answer).

Answer (score 0):

On my system:

```
cat $R_HOME
```

gives nothing, but inside an R session, I get:

```
> Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
[1] "/usr/lib/R"
```

This should tell you two things:

1. that `R_HOME` is set at R's startup, so unless you know exactly what you are doing, maybe you don't need to set it up in your `/etc/profile`.
2. you can use `Sys.getenv` to find out the exact path to your `R_HOME`.