# How do I use source() in R when collaborating across multiple users with different directory structures?

Tags: r, path, environment-variables

I'm collaborating with a few other users on a variety of R projects.  In order to re-use as much code as possible we've created a "stdlib.R" file containing many functions used across multiple projects.

We previously had access to a network drive, so the code could take advantage of the common path by calling:

```
source("f:/code/stdlib.R")
```

But now that we're growing up I don't want to depend upon the existence of the network drive (or any hardcoded path for that matter).  How can I create code that uses a localized path?  Something like this:

```
source("%localusrpath%/stdlib.R")
```

where each user has a way to define what %localusrpath% means to them.

For me it could be C:/temp, for another it could be C:/users/user123/documents.

And as long as they set up that "environment variable" then it's going to work for them.

One solution is to use relative paths only:

```
source("./stdlib.R")
```

But this will fail if the user ever changes their working directory:

```
swd("c:/anything_else")
```

How do I set up a user-specific environment variable through the operating system, and then how can I retrieve/make use of that variable in order to concatenate a path?  Or is this whole thing a bad idea?

Comment: you should make `stdlib.R` a full-on package. it really isn't that much work, esp if you aren't going to submit it to CRAN.

Comment: That is a great suggestion, and I'll probably eventually do that for this particular file.  But I have severl dozen others I want to share with the relative path problem . . . I just chose to ask about one in this thread to simplify the question.  I realize now I should have indicated that I have dozens of files I want to share.

Comment: which makes the creation of a package an even better solution

Comment: agreed . . .will certainly create full packages as the code matures, and we figure out what's going to stick and be discarded or seldom used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in this question:  [setting the home directory in windows R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016907/setting-the-home-directory-in-windows-r)

I did a poor job asking the question, mostly becaue I wasn't sure what I needed.  But ultimately I wanted the code to be portable across multiple computers, each of which will have a Github account.  So, by setting the R_USER system environment on each computer, I can source the files independent of the end user's directory structure.  As long as each end user puts this line in the Rprofile.site file.

```
Sys.setenv(R_USER="/my/desired/path/to/tilde")
source("~/stdlib.R")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not host the stdlib.R file on Github in a repository that you all have admin privileges to? Then you could use `devtools::source_url` to point to the Github repo to source the files.

That way you don't have to worry about everyone having the most up-to-date version on their local machine.

Comment: A very good idea and I'll try to reasearch that more.  However, this is just one of several files I intend to share, and the are all hosted on a private repository.  Ultimately I want our programs to be distributed to serveral people who will not have access to those repositories.  So this sounds like a good solution for development, but not full deployment.