# Error: zipping up workbook failed when trying to write.xlsx

Tags: r, excel

I was trying to write a xlsx file with `write.xlsx` and I get this error:

```
Error: zipping up workbook failed. Please make sure Rtools is installed or a zip application is available to R.
     Try installr::install.rtools() on Windows.

package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

What should I do now to fix this?

**EDIT:**
I install Rtools:

```
>installr::install.rtools()

No need to install Rtools - You've got the relevant version of Rtools installed
```

but still I get that error after `write.xlsx`

Comment: What about installing Rtools? http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: @Stibu, thanks for your comment but it is not working

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @Stibu , I download and install Rtools 3.1 and still I get that error

Comment: @Stibu, I changed the sell path but when I run `shell("PATH")`I don't see Rtools

Answer (score 35):

You should check the `R_ZIPCMD` system variable:

```
Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD", "zip")
```

The default value: "zip". But it can happen that you have to set the environment variable. If you know exactly the location, you can set it:

```
Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD= "C:/SOMETHING_PATH/Rtools/bin/zip")
```

I had the same problem, but setting the `R_ZIPCMD` solved it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this permanently?  It is annoying to have to do this every time I run a new script in a new session.

Comment: For a 'permanent` solution, Plunk this in your .Rprofile: `if(devtools::find_rtools()) Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD= file.path(devtools:::get_rtools_path(),"zip"))`.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39901895/1519199) has more about the why the .Rprofie is not perfect, as does `?startup`

Comment: Or put it in your Windows User Environmental Variables (or however it is called in foreign languages, search the Control Panel)

Answer (score 9):

Install Rtools (for windows) from this location http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
Download the one compatible with your current version of R. While installing check the box for changing the path variable or add "c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;" to path variable afterwards. Start new R session...that works with me..hope this helps..

Comment: great answer.  it might help to clarify this a little:  In Win 7, Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment variables...   then under System variables, find Path, Edit... add to the end ";C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin"   restart RStudio and go.

Answer (score 5):

Try that before write.xlsx:

```
detach(package:openxlsx)

library(xlsx)
```

Comment: Tried, this didn't seem to help

Comment: Tried, this helped.

Answer (score 0):

On my Linux machine, I once got this error when writing a file over the Excel row limit (1,048,576). It was unable to create the file, so produced this message.

If this is your issue, you may need to reshape or truncate your data to have fewer rows. Alternatively, you can try a plain text format which wouldn't have these limits like csv.