# Rscript "there is no package"

Tags: r, data.table, rscript

I have a script that loads data, processes it, and saves the processed data out.  I run it manually without a problem, but it does not work with Rscript.  It uses the data.table package, and Rscript cannot find it.  I have tried [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673000/rscript-there-is-no-package-called) but get the following error message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :   could not find function ".getNamespace" 
In addition: Warning message: package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 3.1.1 Error : unable to load R code in package ‘chron’ 
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘data.table’
Execution halted
```

The script looks like:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)  # Take arguments from command line
library.path <- '/home/zack/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1'
library('data.table', lib.loc = library.path)
```

That code is after failing with library(data.table).  But I can load data.table fine, and so the rest of the script works, if I do this manually.  The command I submit to bash is:

```
nohup /usr/local/bin/Rscript --vanilla <path to script> <args> &
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

which Rscript:

```
/usr/local/bin/Rscript
```

/usr/local/bin/R loads data.table fine when it is called in an interactive session.

Comment: Have you tried updating R and your R packages? Current version of R is 3.2.3. Generally I find that a simple update between mismatched packages/R version solves these kinds of issues.

Comment: do processes runs as same user?

Comment: I just updated to R 3.2.2 and reinstalled data.table.  Do the processes run as the same user?  I think so, in that I am logged on as myself both times, never run as sudo user.

Comment: A possible reason is this: `--vanilla` does not read the user R profile and `.Renviron` file. If you have defined the path to your user library somewhere in these files, the R process started with `--vanilla` will not find the library and the packages installed in it.

Comment: you can check user from R with `Sys.info()[c("user","effective_user")]`

Comment: @jangorecki, user and effective_user are the same.  Stibu, removing --vanilla from the bash command leads to the same error.

Comment: @ZacharyST debug by printing `.libPaths()` and `rownames(installed.packages(lib.loc = ...))`