# Trying to make a scatterplot in R, but struggling to find the sum of monthly rainfall and average monthly humidity to plot

Tags: r

I have previously received help on this issue, and below is the code I was given. As a first time coding/using R, it is hard to understand/manipulate for my specific data set. Initially i was trying to make a scatter plot comparing rainfall (y) and humidity (x), but because the data consists of daily rainfall it consists of a lot of zeroes which makes the scatterplot useless. So now, I am trying to create a scatter plot which gets the average humidity per month (x) and sum of rainfall in that month (y). The dataset is extensive, so to make it easier I just limited myself to the first 5 locations on the dataset: Albury, Badgery Creek, Cobar, Coffs Harbour and Moree, which is around 3000 rows. At the bottom is an example of the first couple of rows of the data set. Is this possible to achieve, and if it is how would I go about adding a Regression to it in order to assess it? Thanks for any help

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
df <- as_tibble(fread('realdata.csv'))
df <- add_column(df, Month = format(as.Date(df$Date), '%B %Y'), .after = 'Date') %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarize(sum(`Rainfall`), mean(`Humidity3pm`))
colnames(df)[2:3] <- c('Total Rainfall (mm)', 'Average 3 PM Relative Humidity (%)')
ggplot(df, aes(x = `Total Rainfall (mm)`, y = `Average 3 PM Relative Humidity (%)`)) + geom_point()
```

[This was the rainfall australia data I took from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/jsphyg/weather-dataset-rattle-package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhTCO.png)

[This is what I'm currently up to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSnBy.png)

[This is the vim attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHc5O.png)

Comment: How your data looks? realdata.csv. paste first few lines with header.

Comment: ok sure thing, i will try

Comment: Date,Location,MinTemp,MaxTemp,Rainfall,Humidity3pm,Pressure3pm,Temp3pm,RainToday,RainTomorrow
1/12/08,Albury,13.4,22.9,0.6,22,1007.1,21.8,No,No
2/12/08,Albury,7.4,25.1,0,25,1007.8,24.3,No,No
3/12/08,Albury,12.9,25.7,0,30,1008.7,23.2,No,No
4/12/08,Albury,9.2,28,0,16,1012.8,26.5,No,No
5/12/08,Albury,17.5,32.3,1,33,1006,29.7,No,No
6/12/08,Albury,14.6,29.7,0.2,23,1005.4,28.9,No,No

Answer (score 0):

First change your date format in you file. Your file looks like:

> Date,Location,MinTemp,MaxTemp,Rainfall,Humidity3pm,Pressure3pm,Temp3pm,RainToday,RainTomorrow
>   1/12/08,Albury,13.4,22.9,0.6,22,1007.1,21.8,No,No
>   2/12/08,Albury,7.4,25.1,0,25,1007.8,24.3,No,No
>   3/12/08,Albury,12.9,25.7,0,30,1008.7,23.2,No,No
>   4/12/08,Albury,9.2,28,0,16,1012.8,26.5,No,No
>   5/12/08,Albury,17.5,32.3,1,33,1006,29.7,No,No
>   6/12/08,Albury,14.6,29.7,0.2,23,1005.4,28.9,No,No

Change it to:

> Day,Month-Year,Location,MinTemp,MaxTemp,Rainfall,Humidity3pm,Pressure3pm,Temp3pm,RainToday,RainTomorrow
>   1,12-08,Albury,13.4,22.9,0.6,22,1007.1,21.8,No,No
>   2,12-08,Albury,7.4,25.1,0,25,1007.8,24.3,No,No
>   3,12-08,Albury,12.9,25.7,0,30,1008.7,23.2,No,No
>   4,12-08,Albury,9.2,28,0,16,1012.8,26.5,No,No
>   5,12-08,Albury,17.5,32.3,1,33,1006,29.7,No,No
>   6,12-08,Albury,14.6,29.7,0.2,23,1005.4,28.9,No,No

You can achieve this format using vim or simple editor. Here in "Date" column I changed the first "/" with "," and second "/" with "-". Open your file in vim by command

```
vim realdata.csv
```

Then type and enter after each line

```
:%s!/!,!g
:%s!,!-!
:%s!,!-!
:%s!-!,!
```

then make change on your header like shown in converted file and save your file by:

```
:x!
```

Then use R with following scripts

```
install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

df <- as.data.frame(read.table("realdata.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE))
df1 <- df %>% group_by(Month.Year) %>% summarize(Rainfall_sum=sum(Rainfall,na.rm=TRUE))
df2 <- df %>% group_by(Month.Year) %>% summarize(Humidity3pm_mean=mean(Humidity3pm,na.rm=TRUE))
df_f <- cbind(df1,df2)
ggplot(df_f, aes(x = df_f[,2], y = df_f[,4])) + geom_point()
```

Comment: struggling to import the dplry library apparently doesn't exist, I'll keep trying

Comment: install.packages('dplyr')

Comment: I've done that a couple of times now, and tried removing it re-installing, restarting with no success, currently looking at a different thread with the same issue still no luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621706/error-in-librarydplyr-there-is-no-package-called-dplyr

Comment: now stuck in this cycle in which R keeps telling me one or more of the packages will be updated by the current installation. Tells me to restart R, so I clicked yes. Presented with the same prompt 2 seconds later

Comment: I am now trying to reinstall R studio

Comment: Finally got dplyr package to work, having an issue with floor_date  saying function doesn't exist

Comment: Hey, I have update the solution. But you need to make little change in your files because your data format standard and separated by slash "/".

Comment: sounds good man, i'll try it now once i figure out the / thing

Comment: if it doesnt work let me know or if works please upvote ;)

Comment: What's an easy way to change the file so that the date is separated by a /. Oh change so separated by dash?

Comment: Yes, so there are a few rows in the "Date" column so i can't manually change the dates to how you said. So how do I change the first / to a , and and second / with -

Comment: I have added the solution in the answer check it out

Comment: The vim realdata.csv returned unexpected symbol

Comment: Use vim directly from terminal not from R console

Comment: Ah i will try that now

Comment: I've just tried to do the vim and i posted a photo of the result, but the pattern after typing the first line did not work

Comment: My dear brother please open existing file name "realdata.csv" not a new file. It seems you are different folder.

Comment: Yeah i thought that might of been the problem. I'm sorry. What should the extension on the excel file be? .csv?

Comment: The file is called realdata.csv, but on the excel file it still looks like an excel file and not a csv file. Not sure

Comment: Ok got the csv uploaded properly this time

Comment: Great what's the status now

Comment: sorry man i fell asleep, i keep trying to upload the proper csv file but i don't think it should be in the table format

Comment: take your time to learn R from here http://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-gapminder/ It will definitely help you in future.