# Executing R Script from WSL Command Line-- Error loading Libraries

Tags: r, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to automate running a R script from a WSL environment. I receive the same error:

```
Error in library(ggplot2) :
there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
Execution halted
```

I have tried solutions from [Rscript: There is no package called ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673000/rscript-there-is-no-package-called) without any result.

I have tried iterations of the test script below.

```
Rscript test.r

signal <- .libPaths(c("C://Program Files//R//R-3.5.3//library", 
"C://Users//USER//Documents//R//win-library//3.5"))

library("ggplot2", lib.loc = signal)

print("Hello World")
```

## ____________________________________________

```
Rscript test.r

signal <- .libPaths()

library("ggplot2", lib.loc = signal)

print("Hello World")
```

## ______________________________________________

```
Rscript test.r -e ".libPaths(c("C://Program Files//R//R-3.5.3//library", 
"C://Users//USER//Documents//R//win-library//3.5"))"

library(ggplot2)

print("Hello World")
```

I believe the error is caused by path set for my libraries. I am wondering if WSL environment is causing an issue with paths featuring the "/mnt/" prefix. I have tried changing the paths to accommodate this without any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the Linux version of R inside WSL:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

If you want to run it from WSL.

Regards

Comment: I do have R 3.5.1

'R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)'

Comment: But in your code, you refer to the Windows version of R

Comment: ah, I see. I was running R Studio on Windows but WSL R version is a separate entity so I needed to install libs in that environment. Thank you!