# Running R from Excel using specific old R packages

Tags: r, shell, version, checkpoint

First time question asker.

I created an Excel/R tool that uses:

- Excel VBA to create a CSV file with data for R,
- Launch R using a Windows Shell,
- Detects when R is finished running and then
- Imports the results in a CSV file created by the R script.

Unfortunately, the R code does not work as programed with some package versions created after *3/1/2020*, which creates problems for new users because they cannot just install the current package versions or users who want to use conflicting versions for other projects.

I have a solution for users who do not require newer versions of R for their other work; writing a script that installs all the packages and their dependents using the “versions” package.  However, I think this approach will constrain users who want to use newer versions of R.  **Is this a correct assumption? **

I thought the `{checkpoint}` package might offer a good solution.  I can get it to run in well in RStudio by creating a RStudio project (where I ran the `{checkpoint}` package to install the 3/1/2020 versions of my packages).  However, I have not found a way to run the R script from the Windows Shell.  The R script does not seem to be able to access the packages installed in the RStudio project using `{checkpoint}`.  **Does anyone have ideas of how I can have Excel VBA launch the start of the R script in a way that it can assess the packages installed in the RStudio project by `{checkpoint}`?** Perhaps there is a Windows Shell call for RStudio similar to the one I use now for R?

Here is the Windows Shell code I currently use for R in case it helps.  It works with the *versions* approach but not the `{checkpoint}` approach.

```
rExeCall = "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\bin\Rscript.exe"
rExeOptns = " --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --verbose  " 
rscrpt=”Tool.R”
Shell (rExeCall & rExeOptns & rscrpt)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

I had hoped that my current R shell code would work when I used `{checkpoint}` to install the correct versions of the packages in an RStudio project.

I tried specifying the `.libPaths` to the file location for the RStudio projection (per [Running R script from PHP in VSCode not recognizing R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60023690/running-r-script-from-php-in-vscode-not-recognizing-r-packages)) without success.

Comment: I dont know if it would help but there is a package (in development): https://github.com/edugca/xlRcode . Take a look!

Comment: Thanks Arthur, this looks interesting.  Is there a way to control where you control where  xlRcode accesses the proper libraries installed in the RStudio project?