# Rscript is not recognising libraries when using renv

Tags: r, renv

I am working on Mac OSX, using v3.6.3 of R and using renv. In Rstudio and R, I can load the libraries of my installed packages, e.g `library(ggplot2)` works.  However when I run a script using Rscript I get the message

```
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

According to this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901895/1299362), I need to make sure that the value of

```
Sys.getenv('R_LIBS_USER') in R.exe
```

is the same as the value of

```
Rscript.exe -e ".libPaths()"
```

But the value is the same, both are pointing to the `renv-system-library` in my project folder.

So how do I fix this?

Comment: It is possible that the `.libPaths()` order could be the issue.  Can you print the first path from the Rscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. akruns answer was useful, it did not work, but pointed me incorrect direction.  The answer did not work because using it, I received the following error:

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion("vctrs")
  error: there is no package called ‘vctrs’
```

Now `vctrs` was in the `'/path/where/library/is/located'` so I think dependent packages were not being loaded from that path but the default for Rscript.  Putting a `print(.libPaths()` in the script gave

```
"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.3_1/lib/R/library"
```

instead of

```
[1] "/Users/Chris/Sites/app_name/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0"
[2] "/private/var/folders/5_/p_yl0439059b7_jdqzrm0hr40000gr/T/RtmptdHcWN/renv-system-library"
```

for `.libPaths()` in Rstudio.  Looking at the ruby program that was actually running the Rscript program, I found it was being run with the --vanilla option, i.e

```
Rscript --vanilla script_name
```

Removing the --vanilla option fixed the problem. I think that scripts with the --vanilla option stopped working because I reinsalled R using brew to fix another problem I was having and as part of this issued this command:

```
brew link --overwrite r
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to specify the `lib.loc` in `library` call

```
library(ggplot2, lib.loc = '/path/where/library/is/located')
```

Comment: I tried that, but received the error  message ```no library trees found in 'lib.loc'```

Comment: @Obromios that is strange.  Can you check the `.libPaths()`, it could be more than one.  Usually, the local one is first checked ffor the package

Comment: That prints out ``` "/Users/Chris/Sites/app_name/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0"          
[2] "/private/var/folders/5_/p_yl0439059b7_jdqzrm0hr40000gr/T/RtmptdHcWN/renv-system-library"```, which is the same as what I am feeding into lib.loc

Comment: ok, can you check in which one of them the ggplot2 is insstalled.  It is possible that when you call from the script without the loc, it is checking a diffferent location

Comment: @Obromios it could be also due to permission.

Comment: We are getting somewhere, but not there yet. The ggplot2 is under ```/Users/Chris/Sites/covid_tracker/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0```, but when I load ggplot2 library with lib.loc equal to that, I get ``` Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
        .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
         call: utils::packageVersion("vctrs")
         error: there is no package called ‘vctrs’```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211587/discussion-between-obromios-and-akrun).